# Call the cast operator of template base class within the derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, casting, virtual

I have a template class, called `Cell`, here the definition:

```
template <class T>
class OneCell
{
.....
}
```

I have a cast operator from `Cell` to T, here

```
virtual operator const T() const
{
   .....
}
```

Now i have derived class, called `DCell`, here

```
template <class T>
class DCell : public Cell<T>
{
.....
}
```

I need to override the Cell's cast operator (insert a little if), but after I need to call the Cell's cast operator. In other methods it's should be something like

```
virtual operator const T() const
{
    if (...)
    {
        return Cell<T>::operator const T;
    }
    else throw ...
}
```

but i got a compiler error

> error: argument of type 'const int (Cell::)()const' does not match 'const int'

What can I do?

Thank you, and sorry about my poor English.

Comment: I you had put the whole code, it would be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually calling the operator:

```
return Cell<T>::operator const T();
```

Full code:

```
template <class T>
class OneCell
{
public:
    virtual operator const T() const
{
        return T();
    }
};

template <class T>
class DCell : public OneCell<T>
{
public:
    virtual operator const T() const
    {
        cout << "operator called";
        return OneCell<T>::operator const T();
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DCell<int> x;
    int y = (int)x;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing parentheses, so the compiler thought you were trying to return the member function, not call it.

```
        return Cell<T>::operator const T();
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code with the implementations of `Cell` and `DCell`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

template<class T>
class Cell
{
protected:
    T cnt;
public:
    Cell(const T& cnt = T()) : cnt(cnt){}
    virtual operator const T() const { return cnt; }
};

bool test_bool = true;

template<class T>
class DCell : public Cell<T>
{
public:
    DCell(const T& cnt = T()) : Cell<T>(cnt){}
    virtual operator const T() const
    {
        if(test_bool)
        {
            return Cell<T>::operator const T(); // Here you had Cell<T>::operator const T;
        } else {
            throw std::exception();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    DCell<int> cell(5);
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(cell) << "\n"; // prints 5 (and a new line)
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the operator virtual.  Instead, delegate to a `protected virtual` helper function.

```
template <class T>
class Cell
{
    public:
        operator const T() const { return cvt_T(); }
    protected:
        virtual const T cvt_T() const;
};

template <class T>
class DCell : public Cell<T>
{
    const T cvt_T() const
    {
        if (...)
        {
            return Cell<T>::cvt_T();
        }
        else throw ...
    }
};
```

This and other good practices can be learned from GotW, [here is the section on virtual architecture](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm).

Comment: @KerrekSB I assume `cvt_T` should be.

Comment: @Kerrek, Luchian: Thanks for pointing that out.  Luchian was correct.